# Drupal - changing form field type from radio to checkboxes

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

Currently I am working on a Drupal 8 project. I have to change a existing form field type from single single selection (radio) to multi selection (checkboxes).

I have changed below

```
$form['job_type'] = [
 '#type' => 'radio',
  '#title' => $this->t('I am looking for'),
  '#options' => [
    'Full-time' => $this->t('Full Time'),
    'Part-time' => $this->t('Part Time'), 
    'Casual' => $this->t('Casual'),
    'All-of-the-above'=>$this->t('All of the above')
  ],
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#required'=>true,
];
```

to

```
$form['job_type'] = [
 '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => $this->t('I am looking for'),
  '#options' => [
    'Full-time' => $this->t('Full Time'),
    'Part-time' => $this->t('Part Time'), 
    'Casual' => $this->t('Casual'),
    'All-of-the-above'=>$this->t('All of the above')
  ],
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#required'=>true,
];
```

This is how save code looks like

```
$profile->set('field_job_type', $form_state->getValue('job_type'));
$profile->save();
```

When the form is submitted, `$form_state->getValue('job_type')` prints the correct selection but when I get the value using `$profile->get('field_job_type')->getValue()` it returns me empty array.

Any help would much appreciated !

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `$form_state->getValue('job_type')` is empty when you are saving the value to `$profile` - have you checked if it returns a value at the point in which it is being saved to `$profile`? Does the `$profile` node definitely have a field called `field_job_type `?

Comment: It would be good to know what kind of 'field_job_type' is. One thing that I can think of is also the type of field "field_job_type" even has ('Full-time', 'Part-time','Casual', 'All-of-the-above') in key field value settings. If the 'field_job_type' is reference you have to apply the value with 'target_id' key instead.

Comment: "field_job_type" is stored in table `field_job_type` in `field_job_type_value` column.

 `field_job_type_value`  is `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: If I print `$form_state->getValue('job_type')` before saving, I can confirm I can see the data.